# VB .Net service will not stop while thread is sleeping

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, sleep

I have a VB .Net service, which uses System.Threading instead of a timer to basically do what a timer should do. My problem is stopping the service while the thread is in its sleep state. See the code below:

```
Imports System.Threading

Public Class AService
    Private stopping As Boolean
    Private stoppedEvent As ManualResetEvent

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        Me.stopping = False
        Me.stoppedEvent = New ManualResetEvent(False)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
        ' Add code here to start your service. This method should set things
        ' in motion so your service can do its work.
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()
        ' Add code here to perform any tear-down necessary to stop your service.
        Me.stopping = True
        Me.stoppedEvent.WaitOne()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ServiceWorkerThread(ByVal state As Object)
        ' Periodically check if the service is stopping.
        Do While Not Me.stopping
            ' Perform main service function here...
            ' do anything here and wait 15 minutes before doing it again
            Thread.Sleep(15 * 60000)  ' Sleep for interval
        Loop

        ' Signal the stopped event.
        Me.stoppedEvent.Set()
    End Sub
End Class
```

If say 1 minutes after the service starts, it can not be stopped until its 15 minute interval ticks and the thread wakes. Is there any way to catch the signal that the service is attempting to stop, and interrupt the thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the code I use.  It has no problem stopping while sleeping or performing.

```
Class MyService
    Inherits ServiceBase

    Private Shared ReadOnly SleepPeriod As New TimeSpan(0, 15, 0)
    Private Shared ReadOnly StopTimeout As New TimeSpan(0, 3, 0)
    Private _TerminationHandle As New ManualResetEvent(False)
    Private _IsRunning As Boolean = False
    Private _ServiceThread As New Thread(Addressof ServiceMain)

    Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(args As String())
        _TerminationHandle.Reset()
        _IsRunning = True
        _ServiceThread.Start()
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()
        _TerminationHandle.Set()
        _IsRunning = False
        ' Terminate the thread if it doesn't stop within 3 minutes of request.
        If Not _ServiceThread.Join(StopTimeout) Then _ServiceThread.Abort()
        _TerminationHandle.Close() ' Can use .Dispose() if using .Net 4.0 or later.
    End Sub

    Private Sub ServiceMain()
        Do
            ' TODO: Do work here.  Watch for "_IsRunning = False" to abort working when stopping.

            ' Sleep for 15 minutes at a time.  Terminate when service is stopping.
        Loop While _IsRunning AndAlso TerminationHandle.WaitOne(SleepPeriod)
        ' TODO: Clean up.
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: _TerminationHandle.Dispose() is not accessible due to its protection level. Any ideas? This is the perfect solution

Comment: I was using .Net 3.5, switched to 4.0 and now its working. I have to do some testing but thanks, this is a great codebase

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware that was a recent addition.  You can use `.Close()` instead in earlier versions of .Net.  I've made a note in the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Hey this turned out to be not what I was looking for. This just seemed to loop my code over and over for 15 minutes, then wait 15 minutes and do it all over again. If you see my original code, Thread.Sleep() was being called before the Loop finished its first time. So that it was essentially a Timer in a thread. I am going to edit your code (that works 100% and is actually ~43% faster than a timer in a service)

Comment: Ok, I edited it! Thanks for your help, this saved my a##. Took me a minute to realize what was going on, but once I realized _IsRunning was always True unless the service was stopping, I looked at my original code and figured it out. Sorry for the late reply. Thanks again! This is my new service base.

Comment: My bad!  I originally used the term `_IsStopping` but changed my mind.  I've fixed the loop logic.  The `OrElse` should be `AndAlso`.

Comment: A NOT is missing. It must be:

    Loop While _IsRunning AndAlso Not _TerminationHandle.WaitOne(SleepPeriod)
Otherwise this just runs once since WaitOne gives back true only when signal was recieved.

Answer (score 1):

In your current model, no.  You are only using a single thread, and your code is explicitly "pausing" the thread for 15 minutes and it's thus unresponsive to any events during that time.

However, if you were to take a slightly improved approach to this, you could improve things: run your `ServiceWorkerThread` sub *in a different thread*, and then your main thread can remain responsive to external events.  When the "stop" signal arrives, you can then abort your worker thread forcefully, if needs be.

Comment: Good explanation about what is going on, give this a try using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `Thread.Interrupt` method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.interrupt.aspx#Y0

However, this requires that you have access to the `Thread` instance which is running your "service." If that's the main thread, then it's a no go, but if it's a thread that you spawn then you can call interrupt and it will interrupt the `Thread` which is in a sleeping/blocking state.

Comment: If you can't move the code into a separate thread, then there is no way around it aside from doing some anti-pattern busy-waits. You can minimize the shut-down "lag" by implementing a solution similar to rerun's, and just set the sleep time to something more acceptable (a couple of seconds or something more along those lines).